# How can I call "Procedures" having IN and OUT params in Anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

In my Play (Scala) application I need to call procedures having IN and OUT params. Can't find any example anywhere !!
I am using Play 2.5x (DB is Oracle).

Comment: No answers so far ?

Comment: You don't mention your exact problem. Assuming that you will return a single result set that you can parse into something in Scala, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740465/anorm-mysql-stored-procedure-calling), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250734/how-to-use-oracle-stored-procedures-with-scala-anorm-in-playframework), while not containing much detail, look relevant. Also, the play docs do make some passing reference to stored proc calling, for example: [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAnorm).

Comment: Added my answer below.

Comment: What have you tried? The out should be also represented as ResultSet so accessible by Anorm mapping (used to do so)

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no mechanism to use Anorm for accessing OUT param of stored procedure. On the other hand the connection object can be used directly and the stored procedure can be called using Java libraries. Refer below example code:

```
dbch.dbprod.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    val cs: CallableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call MY_STORED_PROC(?)}")
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR)
    cs.execute()
    val result = cs.getString(1)
    ....
}
```

Also refer link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html.

Thanks to the hint provided on Play gitter channel.

Comment: Being based on JDBC, out params as ResultSet can be parsed using Anorm